# RDP Fails PCI-DSS Scan

Tags: rdp, pci-dss

I'm having an issue with RDP failing the PCI-DSS scan (port 3389) due to the default self-signed cert that Microsoft Server (2012 R2) generates when RDP is set up.  I need to configure RDP to use a trusted cert.  How would I do that?  I can find nothing out there that explains how that is done.

R/
Prescott ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to the support personnel at Ait.Com for figuring this out for me.  The steps below are specific to Windows Server 2012 r2, can't say that it'll work for any other version.

```
Right click on Windows icon on bottom left and select Run
Enter "gpedit.msc" & hit Enter or click OK
You will see the Group Policy Editor window, on left pane select:
Computer Configuration ->
Administrative Template ->
Windows Components ->
Remote Desktop Services ->
Remote Desktop Session Host ->
Security
Under Security we will change the following settings:
Server authentication certificate template: Select Enabled
inside the input box, enter TLS 1.2 click Apply and OK to close the window
Set client connection encryption level: Select Enabled and on Encryption level dropdown select High Level
Require use of specific security layer for remote (RDP) connections: Select Enabled and on Security layer dropdown select SSL
Require user authentication for remote connections by using Network Level Authentication: Select Enabled
Install the verified TLS 1.2 certificate you bought from a certificate authority:
Right click on Windows icon on bottom left and select Run
Enter MMC & hit Enter or Click OK, a Console1 window will appear
On File menu select Add/Remove snap-in...
Select Certificates on left pane & click the Add button at the center
Select Computer Account & click Next
Select Local Computer & click finish
On left pane select Certificates (Local Computer) -> Personal
Inside Personal folder, you may or may not find a Certificates subfolder, but its ok in either case
If not already, we will import the TLS 1.2 certificate here inside Personal folder Right click -> All Tasks -> Import
By default, Local Machine is selected, click Next
Browse the file path and select the file here, click Next
Enter Password for the certificate & click Next
Select Place All certificates in the following Store, Click Browse to Select Personal folder, we can also select Remote Desktop folder here but only one is required...
Click Next and Click Finish
You should see your certificate inside Personal -> Certificates or Remote Desktop -> Certificate folder (whichever you selected)
Run these commands in power-shell (replace #YourHash# with your Thumbprint from the notepad). run these commands in each line one after the other. PowerShell should show a message that all went successful
$TSGeneralSetting = Get-WmiObject -class "Win32_TSGeneralSetting" -Namespace root\cimv2\terminalservices -Filter "TerminalName='RDP-tcp'" 
$Hash = "#YourHash#"
$TSGeneralSetting.SSLCertificateSHA1Hash = $Hash
$TSGeneralSetting.put()
```